# Time complexity of leetcode 561

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

The questions is:
Given an array of 2n integers, your task is to group these integers into n pairs of integer, say (a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..., (an, bn) which makes sum of min(ai, bi) for all i from 1 to n as large as possible.

The solution provided as:

```
public class Solution {
    public int arrayPairSum(int[] nums) {
        int[] arr = new int[20001];
        int lim = 10000;
        for (int num: nums)
            arr[num + lim]++;
        int d = 0, sum = 0;
        for (int i = -10000; i <= 10000; i++) {
            sum += (arr[i + lim] + 1 - d) / 2 * i;
            d = (2 + arr[i + lim] - d) % 2;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I think it is unfair to say that the time complexity is O(n). Although, O(n+K) K = 20001 is a constant number which seems could be omitted, the n is also less than K. If so, why can't I say time complexity to be O(1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotic complexity is measured as a function of n, for ALL n. We are concerned with what happens when n gets large. Really, really large.

Maybe in practice n will always be tiny. Fine.

But when you give a complexity measure for an algorithm, you are by definition saying what happens as n grows. And grows and grows. And when it does, it will dwarf K.

So O(n) it is.

Clarification:

It is true that the problem specification says:

> n is a positive integer, which is in the range of [1, 10000].
>
> All the integers in the array will be in the range of [-10000, 10000].

But remember, that is just for this problem! The solution given hard codes the value of K. The *algorithm* used here should indeed be written as O(n + K), as you noticed. This K is not a constant factor and probably should not be dropped.

However with asymptotic complexity (Big-O, Big-Theta, etc.) even with an arbitrary but finite K, you can still find constants k and N such that for all n>N, kn > the number of operations needed in this algorithm, which is the Big-O definition. This is why you will see a lot of people say O(n).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You are right. Based on the definition of O, it should be O(n) no matter what.